# Listening for keywords at all times, like "Ok google" on 4.4

Tags: android, speech-recognition, android-4.4-kitkat

I've checked the new Kitkat libraries to make sure that I'm not missing something. I want my application to always listen to a keyword before performing an action, just like how Google Now always listens for the keywords "Ok google" on the homescreen.

How did Google accomplish this?

Comment: Google achieve this at CPU level and unfortunately there's little hope of it being included in a public SDK - Only OEMs have access. See this link: https://developer.qualcomm.com/forum/qdevnet-forums/mobile-technologies/snapdragon-sdk/27006 Replicating this ability in other ways is extremely resource intensive.

Comment: Hey I am trying to do a simple keyword spotting in my service, so that I can listen for the word "hello". Unfortunately it is not working. Please help me: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35388720/cant-start-service-speech-recog

Answer (score 11):

What you need is called [keyword spotting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keyword_spotting). Apart from online speech API Android has offline recognizer which is a bit more sophisticated. It is not mentioned in official documentation, but you can see the sources [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.3_r2.1/android/speech/srec/Recognizer.java), for example. I'm not sure you will find keyword spotting there, but at least you will have access to low-level recognizer interfaces.

**UPD:** Keyword spotting and voice activity detection are now implemented in [pocketsphinx](https://github.com/cmusphinx/pocketsphinx/) and [pocketsphinx-android](https://github.com/cmusphinx/pocketsphinx-android/). See [the official demo](https://github.com/cmusphinx/pocketsphinx-android-demo/) to see them both in action.

Answer (score 1):

Services can be kept running in the background! They probably invoked it by setting a broadcast receiver to receive the boot completed broadcast and invoking a service which is set to listen for the phrase.

Comment: I know. However, this was a very complex thing to do before 4.4. I'm just wondering if there's an easier way on 4.4, as the base-code  seems to be implemented in 4.4 for this. And that is the easy part, the complex part is actually listening for the phrase continuously. Pre-4.4 you had to restart the speech recognition service every 4 seconds because the service stopped when there was no input.