# Javascript / Browser Speech recognition of made up word

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, speech-recognition, grammar

I want to use browser based speech recognition on my web app, and I want to give a "wake up" command using a made up word (the name of my app) in much the same way as the Amazon Echo wakes up when you say "Alexa"

I was hoping that I could add it as a grammar, however this does not seem to work (or I am pronouncing it wrong!)

My setup looks like this (I'm using chrome)

```
console.log("Start Of Speech")
var recognition = new webkitSpeechRecognition();
recognition.continuous = true;
recognition.interimResults = true;

var grammar = '#JSGF V1.0; grammar startme; public <startme> = madeupwordtostart | madeupwordtostop;'
var speechRecognitionList = new webkitSpeechGrammarList();
speechRecognitionList.addFromString(grammar, 1);
recognition.grammars = speechRecognitionList;
```

Is this the right approach, or am I expecting too much?

I realise that there are flaws in this (microphone timing out, granting permission each time etc) - it's only a side project at the moment!

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible with Web Speech API. The API lacks [keyword spotting](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20317872/1746434), and the grammar search cannot implement it properly because once started, the search never rolls back, and thus any silence, noise, false words will confuse it more it more.